# T-SQL query to summarize sales for ALL YEARS: with total per month per year, and cumulative monthly amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a Sales Report that shows all years sales per month, and cumulative sales. 
The database table is simple:

```
Transactions 
(
    ID INT, 
    TransactionDate DATETIME, 
    SalesAmount MONEY
)
```

I want the results to look similar to ExcelSheet below (I am showing only 2017/2018 amounts, but actual query needs to return results for all available years according to TransactionDate)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
With Q 
as
(
   Select DatePart(yyyy,TransactionDate) 'Year',DatePart(m,TransactionDate) 'Month',  sum(SalesAmount) 'Sales'
   From Transactions 
   Group by DatePart(yyyy,TransactionDate),DatePart(m,TransactionDate)
) 
Select q.Year,q.Month,q.sales,( Select sum(q1.Sales)
        From Q q1
        Where q1.Year=q.Year
         And  q1.Month <= q.Month
        ) 'Cumulative Sale'
From Q q
Order by q.Year,q.Month
```

Comment: @DavidRokni . . . Window functions are definitely a better choice than a correlated subquery in this case.

Answer (score 3):

This is aggregation and a cumulative sum:

```
select year(TransactionDate), month(TransactionDate),
       sum(SalesAmount),
       sum(sum(SalesAmount)) over (partition by year(TransactionDate) order by min(TransactionDate))
from Transactions
group by year(TransactionDate), month(TransactionDate)
order by year(TransactionDate), month(TransactionDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with cte as
(
select year(TransactionDate) as Year, month(TransactionDate) as Month, SalesAmount 

)

 select a.Year, a.Month, a.SalesAmount, sum(b.SalesAmount) as cumulativeSalesAmount 
 from Transactions  a inner join Transactions  b on a.STORE_ID = b.STORE_ID and a.Year = b.Year and a.Month >= b.Month
 group by a.Year, a.Month
 order by 1, 2
```